How to find the property which has the highest value
let obj1 = { 1:1,2:1,4:3};

I want to get the property 4 as the output because the value of that property is highest of all other properties. I am trying to find out the highest frequency number in my own way.
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];
let arr1Obj = {};

function findMaxFreq(arr, arr1Obj) {
  let freqArr = [];
  let objarrvalue = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let frequencyOf = arr[i];
    let count = 1;
    for (let j = arr[i]; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] === arr[j]) {
        count++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    arr1Obj[arr[i]] = count;
  }
  let objvalues = Object.values(arr1Obj);
  for (let i = 0; i < objvalues.length; i++) {
    if (objvalues[i] > objarrvalue) {
      objarrvalue = objvalues[i];
    }
  }
  return objarrvalue;
}

console.log(findMaxFreq(arr1, arr1Obj));


does it work? what goes wrong?

I believe if I can get your question correct, you want to get the maximum occurring number of a given array, say number 4 appeared more than 3 times than any other number.
Here is how you can achieve that:
I added a lot of comments to help you understand how I solved it.



let number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]

let obj = {}

function maxNumOccurence(num) {
   if (num.length === 0) {
        // return null for an empty array
       return null; 
   }

   /** `occurenceNum` object created to keep track of the count of each element */  
   const occurenceNum = {};
   let maxNum = num[0];
   let maxCount = 1;

   /**  We iterate through the array, `num`, updating the count for each element */  
   for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    const number = num[i]

    // if iterated number is undefined, return one
    if(occurenceNum[number] === undefined) {
        occurenceNum[number] = 1;
    } else {
        occurenceNum[number]++;
    }
    // If we find an element with a higher count, maxCount, we update
    if (occurenceNum[number] > maxCount) {
        maxNum = number;
        // console.log(maxNum) => {4, 4, 4}
        maxCount = occurenceNum[number];
    }
   }
   return maxNum
}


// console.log the function with any array parameter of numbers, will return the max occurence count of the said array.

console.log(maxNumOccurence(number))



You could do it like that:


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];

function findMaxFreq(arr){
  let counts = {}, max = null, maxCount = 0;
  for(const n of arr){
    const count = n in counts ? ++counts[n] : counts[n] = 1;
    if(count > maxCount) max = n, maxCount = count;
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(findMaxFreq(arr));



If the input array is sorted:


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];

let count = 1, n = arr[0], maxCount = 1, max = n;
for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] !== n){
    if(count > maxCount) max = n, maxCount = count;
    count = 1, n = arr[i];
    if(maxCount > arr.length - i) break; // no more elements to beat the max
  } else {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(max);




May I know if this will result in running two loops?

you can use cache technique in this case like this:
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];
let arr1Obj = {};

function findMaxFreq(arr, obj){
  const cacheObj = arr.reduce((prev, next)=>{
    if (prev[next]) {
        prev[next]++
        return prev;
    }else{
        prev[next] = 1;
        return prev;
    }
  }, Obj);
  let highestFreq = 0;
  for(key in cacheObj){
     if(cacheObj[key] >= highestFreq){
           highestFreq = +key
     }
   }
  return highestFreq;
}


You could take a single loop with an array for collecting max frequency values, because of the possibillity of having two or more values with same frequency.
At then end return either a single value, if only one value is available or an array of values.


function findMaxFreq(array) {
    const counts = {};
    let max;
    for (const value of array) {
        counts[value] = (counts[value] || 0) + 1;
        if (!max || counts[value] > counts[max[0]]) {
            max = [value];
            continue;
        }
        if (counts[value] === counts[max[0]] && !max.includes(value)) max.push(value);
    }
    return max.length === 1
        ? max[0]
        : max;
}

const
    values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];

console.log(findMaxFreq(values));




You can use .map and .filter on the array to achieve that.


let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5];

function findMaxFreq(arr) {
    let arr1Obj = {};

    let freqArray = arr.map((elem) => {
        return { [elem]: arr.filter((value) => value === elem).length };
    });

    freqArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (!arr1Obj.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(element)[0])) {
            arr1Obj[Object.keys(element)[0]] = Object.values(element)[0];
        }
    });

    let max = Object.keys(arr1Obj).find(
    (key) => arr1Obj[key] === Math.max(...Object.values(arr1Obj)));

    return max;
}

console.log("Original Array: ", arr1);
console.log("After function: ", findMaxFreq(arr1));



